# Is there a combination of colors which make code easier to scan/read in a text editor (can you provide an example)?

Tags: colors

I believe color choice is not something purely subjective.

And even less subjective while programming.

Which combination and use of colors may improve readability of the code?

Can you give an example? (a Vim scheme if possible).

(I'm not sure if it is relevant but I do PHP, XHTML, CSS, and jQuery).

Comment: Just a small hint when it comes to OOP: recently I discovered that using different color/font style for method parameters vs. local method variables helps a lot. Of course different color for fields is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also found that the higher the *“tutti frutti” factor*, the more distracting something gets. In that regard, the "adrian" color scheme (from the [VIM color scheme list](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-java.html)) uses at least 7 (foreground,background) pairs, while the "adaryn" scheme suffices with 4 in the screenshot. (That is not to say that no highlighting is the most helpful.)

Particularly, many color schemes try to colorize *everything* and everything *differently*, leading to this tutti frutti effect — such as to distinguish between the "public static void" and "import foo" parts (also see VIM color list).

What I prefer is that colors are given to the following 5–6 "units", in descending importance order, i.e. if there is only a limited set of colors, give them away in the rank order before using the default terminal color for the rest:

- rank 1: keywords, /* comments */
- rank 2: "string literals"
- rank 3: operators, other punctuation (braces, etc.).
- rank 4 (optional): C, C++ preprocessor

Give each of these its own color without overlaps (minus terminal default consideration).

Having a consistent background colors seems essential. (The "cool" VIM scheme fails that, basically.)

Answer (score 1):

It's all about [contrast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_%28vision%29). High contrast is good, low contrast is bad.

Look at some [color schemes](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-java.html) and decide for yourself (no opinion can beat personal preference).

Answer (score 0):

[Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) is a color scheme created in order to ease reading. It fits very well with coloring syntax of code with vim

Here is the description of this colorshcheme, given on its website:

> Solarized is a sixteen color palette (eight monotones, eight accent
>   colors) designed for use with  terminal and gui applications. It has
>   several unique properties. I designed this colorscheme with both
>   precise CIELAB lightness relationships and a refined set of hues based
>   on fixed color wheel relationships. It has been tested extensively in
>   real world use on color calibrated displays (as well as
>   uncalibrated/intentionally miscalibrated displays) and in a variety of
>   lighting conditions.

I use it for z80, python, latex and I'm happy of the result.

Configuration for vim is available [here](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized)